# Ensure component can only child of specific parent components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I want to be able to define a list of components that can be immediately above Child Component in the component hierarchy. Is there a programmatic way to check for this?

The list would basically be an array of classes like

```
const allowed_parents  = [Parent1, Parent2, Parent3];
```

and then

```
<UnListedParent>
  .
  .
  .
  <Child />
</UnListedParent>
```

should throw an error

Comment: You can use any number of testing libraries to check for this.  Jest is a popular choice for React.

Comment: And if you use it in `const UnlistedParent = () => <div><Child /></div>` format than it is ok? Which means it is a child too, just not in a JSX tree.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I see I'll look into the jest api to see if it's possible to check for that. @gazdagergo no since that would make `Child` an immediate child of `UnlistedParent`. Basically I want to ensure that Child can only be used if it is wrapped inside a listed parent component

Comment: is this a testing question? or do you ask about a possibility to check it in the main runtime?

Comment: My ListedParent iterates through Child Component immediately under them with `props.children`. So I want to ensure that Child Component can only be used immediately under ListedParent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the parent directly from a child with any known public React API.

There are "hacky" ways of course, like, to `createRef` on the parent and pass it down to the child, using `React.Children.map`, and `React.cloneElement` programmatically, but this is such a bad design, that I am not going to even post it here, to not be associated with that code :D

I think a better approach, though, that aligns better with the `React` philosophy and unidirectional top-down flow is to use a combination of HigherOrderComponent-wrapped "allowed parents" that pass a specific flag onto children they "allow", and subsequently check in the child if flag exists or error out otherwise.

That could go approximately something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/w78042y66k)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Child = ({ isAllowed }) => {
  if (!isAllowed) {
    throw new Error("We are not allowed!");
  }

  return <div>An allowed child.</div>;
};

const allowParentHOC = Wrapper => {
  return ({ children, ...props }) => {
    return (
      <Wrapper {...props}>
        {React.Children.map(children, child =>
          React.cloneElement(child, {
            isAllowed: true
          })
        )}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  };
};

const Parent1 = allowParentHOC(props => <div {...props} />);
const Parent2 = allowParentHOC(props => <div {...props} />);

const UnListedParent = ({ children }) => children;

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { hasError: false };

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true, info });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return (
        <>
          <h1>This Child was not well put :(</h1>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.info, null, 2)}</pre>
        </>
      );
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isUnAllowedParentShown: false
  };

  handleToggle = () =>
    this.setState(({ isUnAllowedParentShown }) => ({
      isUnAllowedParentShown: !isUnAllowedParentShown
    }));

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleToggle}>Toggle Versions</button>
        {this.state.isUnAllowedParentShown ? (
          <UnListedParent>
            <Child />
          </UnListedParent>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Parent1>
              <Child />
            </Parent1>
            <Parent2>
              <Child />
            </Parent2>
          </>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <App />
  </ErrorBoundary>,
  rootElement
);
```