# React and Typescript: components are props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prop

I'm making app using React and Typescript. I can't figure out how to hint that only one component type can be used as attribute. Here is an example.

in `AuthLayout.tsx`:

```
import React, { ReactNode, ReactElement } from 'react';
import { Trans } from '@lingui/react';

type Props = {
  title: ReactElement<any, typeof Trans>,
  children: ReactNode
}

var x = React.createElement(Trans)

function AuthLayout(props: Props) {
    const {children, title} = props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

export default AuthLayout;
```

But then if I try to use it in another file like this:

```
<AuthLayout title={<AnyComponent />}>
  hey <br/>
</AuthLayout>
```

it works just fine. How do I declare it so `title` atribute will only accept `Trans` component?

Comment: If you want title to accept only Trans component as value, why can't it be hardcoded inside the AuthLayout instead of passing it as a props?

Comment: remove any from `title: ReactElement<any, typeof Trans>`?

Comment: I recently asked (and got an answer to) something very similar. I dont want ot reiterate, so [here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54674772/8433471) to that answer.